# Trying to use template literals to have the following '"$music" from:username' in js

Tags: javascript

I need to have the following output

```
'"$music" from:username'
```

the variables for the `music` part are `req.body.title` and the username is `req.body.twitter`

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do these with concatenation or template literals I have tried this which works

`` query: `"$music" from:${req.body.twitter}`, ``

but not sure how to get the whole `"$music"` part from the variable `req.body.title` in there, if it's not this format it fails on the twitter search API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: `${music}`? You got it right for the second part.

Comment: What is the value of `req.body.title`, that exact string? Then just do `\`${req.body.title} from:${req.body.twitter}\``.

Comment: the value of the string is `music` and I tried that and it does not work because I need the $ and the value to wrapped inside double quotes inside single quotes around the whole thing "$music" inside the single quotes '"$music" from:username'

Comment: I need the exact output of that single quote double quote with $ and the value of the  variable being music

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a terrible question, but this is what I had to do

```
  query: `"$${req.body.title}" from:${req.body.twitter}`,
```